# How does this show that this homomorphism is onto?

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image: pg]

How does $\varphi (x,e') = x$ for all $x\in G$ show that this homomorphism is surjective? I'm not sure how this fits the definition of surjectivity.

Comment: To prove surjectivity, you need to show that given any element $y \in G$, there exists an element $(x, x') \in G \oplus G'$ such that $\varphi(x, x') = y$. Is there any obvious candidate?

Comment: On a more important note, it is discouraged that you use pictures in your questions. Consider editing the question and type it out instead. (You only need type out the relevant parts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surjective means *every point in the target of a function lies in the image of the function*. Hence picking any $x \in G$ you have to show it lies in the image of $\varphi$, which it does, since $\varphi(x,e‘)=x$...